# MFMailComposeViewController Swift - Set orientation mode as portrait only

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using a MFMailComposeViewController how do i set the orientation mode to portrait only

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18505512/988169).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MFMailComposeViewController` is just a ViewController. So, what you can do, it is create your own subclass of `MFMailComposeViewController` and override orienattion methods as you want.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}
```

Comment: Can you please add swift code, as when i try this compiler is complaining that it cannot override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Comment: These functions are not called when i add them to my viewcontroller which is a inherited from MFMailComposeViewController, Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

The basic format is `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angle )` where `angle` is a `CGFloat` in radians. You can easily `rotate` any `object` with under below sample codes, Also that codes `advantage` is **if your project only landscape dont care that codes turn your view to portrait**

Use this;

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
       // Set whatever frame you want
          self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))


    }
```

Also you can rotate your view change with : `-M_PI_2`

- `M_PI` = π = 180 degrees
- `M_PI_2` = π/2 = 90 degrees
- `M_PI_4` = π/4 = 45 degrees

Comment: So, how would you know how many degrees you need to set?
Also, in your code, how you will handle orientation changes?

Comment: @PavelGatilov i wrote working viewWillAppear codes just use it will be set it for portrait.